# How to find out which font can display these characters?

Tags: linux, shell, fonts, imagemagick

```
⚫⚪
Unicode U+26AB
Unicode U+26AA
```

[image]

This two characters can be display in terminal, I want use `convert`(imagemagick command) to convert those text into picture.

But `convert` only can use **one special font**, not fallback font could be used.

> convert -list font

So how can I find which font could display those characters?

Comment: Not sure what your question really is. Do you want to know the name of a font? Or do you want to know how to generate unicode characters? Or do you want to know the unicode symbols for a black and a white circle - I think they are `25CB` and `26AB`? Or do you want to know how to specify a font in an **ImageMagick** command?

Comment: I want the **really** font name which can display this two characters just as the screenshot showed in my terminal. Of course the default terminal font can not display it, it must used some fallback font family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted the code in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452828), to make a script to find which font contains a particular character as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys
import unicodedata
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from sys import platform

def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
    for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
        if cmap.isUnicode():
            if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
                return True
    return False

def test(char):
    for fontpath in fonts:
        font = TTFont(fontpath)   # specify the path to the font in question
        if char_in_font(char, font):
            print(char + " "+ unicodedata.name(char) + " in " + fontpath)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if platform == "linux":
        likelyPlaces = ['/usr/share/fonts', '/usr/local/share/fonts', '~/.fonts']
    elif platform == "darwin":
        likelyPlaces = ['/System/Library/Fonts', '/Library/Fonts', '~/Library/Fonts']
    elif platform == "win32":
        likelyPlaces = ['WHO KNOWS']

    fonts = []
    for place in likelyPlaces:
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.path.expanduser(place)):
            for file in files:
               if file.endswith(".ttf"): fonts.append(os.path.join(root,file))

    # Check user has specified a character
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: findfont.py glyph")

    test(sys.argv[1])
```

So, I can now call it as follows to find the font containing your two circles:

[image]

Comment: Yes, after install `python3-fonttools`, your script list all fonts which contain this character. I can pick up each font and test. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fc-list` :

```
fc-list :charset=26AA,26AB
```

It will list the installed fonts which support both characters.

See also [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1430497/8822) with a few more details.