# Font and unicode - PIL in python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, fonts, python-imaging-library

I would like to use font from LaTeX or a similar one. Why in this font does not work Unicode? Are some fonts appropriate to Unicode and some of them not? Which font should I use? Many thanks

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter

font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)
unicode_text = u"\u03B2 Hello"

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans.ttf", 40)
font = ImageFont.truetype('lmroman7-regular.otf', 40)

draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )
draw.text ( (20,40), unicode_text, font=font, fill=font_color )

im.save("text.jpg")
```

I have the file with the font in the same directory as the python code. I am looking for LM Roman font for download that would be able to display beta.

Comment: By "font from LaTeX", do you mean the LM Roman one? According to the file extension (.otf), it's an Open Type font, not True Type (.ttf). As `ImageFont` has a method `truetype`, but no method `opentype`, chances are the latter is not supported by PIL.

Comment: Yes, I mean LM Roman. I downloaded this font https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman , which has .ttf extension. The result is a rectangle instead of beta

Comment: If you run the script in this answer, you can find all your fonts capable of displaying that beta... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057237/2836621

Comment: Thank you. What should I write to the terminal? I tried `python3 font_find.py u03B2` and `python3 font_find.py \u03B2`

Comment: No, use `font_find β`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CMU-serif](https://www.ceskefonty.cz/ceske-fonty/computer-modern-unicode-serif) is an appropriate font similar to LM Roman with Greek letters available

Answer (score 0):

what was the error? I ran your code it gave me error `OSError: can not open resource`. if it's the case, then you should give font address instead of font name. `PIL` can support `.oft` fonts too. but I am not sure this Unicode `(\u03B2)` is going to give you a rectangular. here is your code (hope it helps):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import os
# __file__ is the path for your code file
directory,filename = os.path.split(__file__)

font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)
unicode_text = "\u03B2 Hello"

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
# if the font is installed in your computer use this code
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf", 40)
#if it's in the same folder as the code, use this code
font = ImageFont.truetype(directory + "\\lmroman10-regular.otf", 40)
draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )
draw.text ( (20,40), unicode_text, font=font, fill=font_color )

im.save("text.jpg")
```

Comment: I have the font in the same folder as the code. I am totally comfused from all folders with fonts I found in my computer. Nevertheless, I did not find any .ttf extension or LM Roman at the first glance; therefore I downloaded other and gave it to the directory with code together.

Comment: hey @ElenaGreg I just updated the answer. but I am still confusing about your situation. if your code does not recognize the font then you can use the answer. if your problem is about printing a rectangular on an image, then I suppose you search around for other fonts or other unicodes. but you still did not answer my question what was the error?